# how to extract from a bgen file carriers for a specific variant with plink

Tags: genetics

I have a bgen file with million of variants for ~5k people. Now, I need to find individuals carrying a specific variant of interest with plink.

Do you know a way to do it with plink 1.9 or plink 2?

thanks!